# Want to find an example of a linear mapping T on V such that kerT is not equal to ImT though T^2=O,where O denotes the zero operator on V.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have proved that if T:V->V be a linear map then KerT=ImT iff dim V is two.So,in order to find out such example we need only to find out a linear map on a vector space whose dimension is odd.But here I fail to have such examples which meet my purpose.Please give me proper example.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $T^2$ to be 0 you need $\text{Im T}\subseteq \text{ker T}$, but they don't have to be equal. The simplest example would be $T(1,0,0)=0,T(0,1,0)=0,T(0,0,1)=(1,0,0)$ so $\text{ker T}=\text{span}\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ and $\text{Im T}=\text{span}\{(1,0,0)\}$.

I do not understand your claim about the iff since a similar example can be easily constructed for even dims as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim that

$$\ker T = T(V) \iff \dim V=2 $$

Is unfortunately incorrect, in fact neither direction of implication is true in general. Consider $V=\mathbb{R}^4$ and let

\begin{align}
 T:V&\to V \\
(1,0,0,0) &\mapsto (0,0,0,1) \\
(0,1,0,0) &\mapsto (0,0,1,0) \\
(0,0,1,0) &\mapsto (0,0,0,0)\\
(0,0,0,1) &\mapsto (0,0,0,0) 
\end{align}

I'll leave it to you to check that the image and kernel align. For the other direction, note that $Id_{\mathbb{R}^2}$, the identity map on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is linear, and its kernel and image do not align.

Answer (score 0):

With $T=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ we have $T^2=0$, hence $im(T)\subseteq \ker(T)\neq 0$, so that
$$
\ker(T)\cap im(T)=im(T)\neq 0,
$$
and also $\ker (T)\neq im(T)$. Here the size of the matrix, $n=2$ is even.